# Cast ssize_t or size_t

Tags: c++, casting, size-t

In source files which I am using in my project, there is a comparison between `ssize_t` and `size_t` variables:

```
ssize_t sst;
size_t st;

if(sst == st){...}
```

I would like to get rid of the warning:

```
warning: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions
```

But I am not sure, which variable should I cast to the other?

```
if((size_t)sst == st){...}
```

or

```
if(sst == (ssize_t)st){...}
```

What is safer, better, cleaner? Thanks

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Try to prepend `(signed int)` before the unsigned integer. It should now both be a signed integer and wouldn't throw the error anymore.

Comment: @Allendar: casting a `size_t` to an `int` is a recipe for disaster. On 64 bit platforms, `int` is usually only 32 bits wide.

Comment: +1 @larsmans.  And even if they were the same size, if the unsigned value isn't representable in the signed variable, it causes implementation-defined behaviour, making the code (presumably) less portable.

Comment: @Allendar: I really, really hope to never see anyone do that.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is no one right answer to this question.  There are several possible answers, depending on what you know *a priori* about the values that those variables may take on.

- If you know that `sst` is non-negative, then you can safely cast `sst` to `size_t`, as this will not change the value (incidentally, this is what happens if you have no cast at all).
- If `sst` might be negative but you know that `st` will never be larger than `SSIZE_MAX`, then you can safely cast `st` to `ssize_t`, as this will not change the value.
- If `sst` might be negative, and `st` might be larger than `SSIZE_MAX`, then neither cast is correct; either one could change the value, resulting in an incorrect comparison.  Instead, you would do the following `if (sst >= 0 && (size_t)sst == st)`.

If you’re not *absolutely certain* that one of the first two situations applies, choose the  third option as it is correct in all cases.

Comment: +1 for the simpler expression - there's no reason to have the `(st <= SSIZE_MAX)` I included in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Either will work fine as long as both values fit in the positive representable range of `ssize_t`.

If either value *doesn't*, you could end up in trouble - check those cases before testing for equality:

```
if ((sst >= 0) && (st <= SSIZE_MAX) && (sst == (ssize_t)st))
{
  ...
}
```

(I'm sure the C++ people will recommend you avoid the C-style cast entirely - I have no doubt someone will comment or answer and let you know the right way to do that in C++.)

Comment: Once you rule out `sst < 0`, you can just convert to `size_t` and compare.

Comment: `static_cast<ssize_t>(st)` is a slightly safer C++ cast.