# error: comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions

Tags: c

I am getting above cited error when compiling following code.

```
long _version_tag;
size_t _timing;

ssize_t bytes_read = read(fd, &_version_tag, sizeof(long));
if (bytes_read < sizeof(long) || _version_tag != TIMING_FILE_VERSION_TAG)
    return -1;
```

gcc complains at this point:

```
   if (bytes_read < sizeof(long) || _version_tag != TIMING_FILE_VERSION_TAG)
                           ^
```

I haved even tried to explicitly cast **bytes_read** to **long** but in vain. Can somebody please help what's going on here?

Comment: `if (bytes_read < (ssize_t) sizeof(long) )`  Assuming there was some good reason for byte_read to be signed, we must want a signed comparison, so we cast the constant `sizeof(long)` to the same type as `bytes_read`.  But if there is really no chance `bytes_read` is negative, the opposite cast may make more sense `(size_t)bytes_read<sizeof(long)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[read(3)](http://linux.die.net/man/3/read) returns -1 if it fails, so test for that first. If it succeeded, then you can test the length. Something like:

```
ssize_t bytes_read = read(fd, &_version_tag, sizeof(long));

if (bytes_read == -1 || (size_t)bytes_read < sizeof(long) || _version_tag != TIMING_FILE_VERSION_TAG)
    return -1;
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that `bytes_read` is of type `ssize_t` which is signed while `sizeof(long)` is of type `size_t` which is unsigned.

As `sizeof(long)` will never be too big to be represented as `ssize_t` on any system I can imagine, I would recommend to cast the result of `sizeof(long)` to `ssize_t`:

```
bytes_read < (ssize_t)(sizeof(long)) // Or static_cast in C++
```

---

This is usually just a warning, not an error as the result is well defined by the standard. However, implicit comparison of signed and unsigned integer types can have surprising results and should thus be avoided.

Comment: `ssize_t` is signed for a reason, and `read()` returns signed for a reason: a negative value signals an error. He should explicitly check this return value before doing the cast. Not really a wrong answer, but incomplete.

Comment: @NickCano Hm? As I cast the RHS to signed, a negative `bytes_read` will make the comparison evaluate to `true`, which seems to be desired.

Comment: Unless, for whatever reason, there's something in the code defining a type of `long` that is larger than the maximum value of `ssize_t`, then you are correct. That likely will never be the case, but OP should still do the explicit check IMHO. I'll remove the DV, it was a bit hasty. EDIT: apparently can't remove a DV on SO ? :(

Comment: @NickCano Now you can.

Comment: True that "sizeof(long) will never be to big to be represented as ssize_t", the question is more about "comparison between signed and unsigned integer expressions".  A more general solution would be independent of the size of `_version_tag`.

Comment: @chux Sorry, I did not get that. The `_version_tag` comparison has nothing to do with the question and the warning and my answer afaics.

Comment: This answer uses `long` as in `bytes_read < (ssize_t)(sizeof(long))` because that is what OP did and certainly because `long` is the type of `_version_tag`.  It relies on `_version_tag` not being some enormous size object.  Of course, in OPs' example, it is small.  A generic test would be `if (bytes_read < 0 || (size_t) bytes_read < sizeof(_version_tag) || ...`

Comment: @chux Ok, correct. I am confident that this will never happen on any system I work on. Feel free to post the more general answer.

Answer (score 1):

Various answers offer the solution to solve the warning caused by `bytes_read < sizeof(long)` to cast one side of the comparison to the type of the other side.

```
(size_t) bytes_read < sizeof(long) // or
bytes_read < (ssize_t) sizeof(long)
```

If the first approach is taken, then a preceding test should occur.

```
bytes_read == -1
```

Lots of comments reflect on the merits of casting one side of the other.  Casting is always a bit tricky for there exist the potential for demoting casting (going to a reduced range) and losing information.

In OP's example of reading into `long _version_tag`, it **makes no difference** which side was cast as `long` is certainly has a *size* less than 32,767 - the smallest maximum value of `ssize_t` and less than 65,535 - the smallest maximum value of `size_t`.

---

If looking for a general solution and not assuming `_version_tag` is a `long`, but potential something far larger, and using [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16086331/2410359), then code could use the following.  Code knows the value in `bytes_read`, if not -1, must fit in a `size_t` as it certainly will be no larger than what was passed to `read()`.

```
foo _version_tag;
ssize_t bytes_read = read(fd, &_version_tag, sizeof _version_tag);

if (bytes_read == -1 || (size_t) bytes_read < sizeof _version_tag || ...)
  return -1;
```

For my part, I eschew casting and prefer multiplying to avoid down-casting.

```
if (bytes_read == -1 || ((size_t)1 * bytes_read) < sizeof _version_tag || ...)
  return -1;
```

Comment: Ref link is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
ssize_t
```

is a signed type, but the result of sizeof is `size_t` which is an unsigned type. In C if you want to avoid the warning/error you can cast the `sizeof` result to `ssize_t`.

Comment: NMDV, but this [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33899665/error-comparison-between-signed-and-unsigned-integer-expressions#comment55562386_33899760) applies here too.  Casting `bytes_read` leads to a more generic solution.

Comment: @chux I'm answering the specific question asked by OP, that is: why he got the warning/error in the first place. Downvoting my answer and his is truly amazing.

Comment: True that down-voting this answer and/or the post is unwarranted.  Neither of which I did.

Comment: I do like the simplicity of this answer as it does work in OP's example.

Answer (score -2):

`ssize_t` is signed, where `size_t` is unsigned. You first need to make sure `bytes_read` is non-negative (meaning the call did not fail). If that check passes, you can just do `bytes_read < static_cast<ssize_t>(sizeof(long))`.

Comment: @Black_Zero Which raises the question why you tagged this C++.

Comment: For the larger benefit of society. I can not use the suggested code in my project but others can.